# How do I successfully rebase a branch onto a (github) squashed commit containing the commits it was branched off of?

Tags: git, github

I am now unlucky enough to be stuck using github and github flow branching strategy at work. I don't like github. It has the worst implementations of pull requests I've seen, and it's CR tool makes me want to puke, but that's not the (main) problem.

Our branch history currently looks like this:

```
A---B---E' main
     \
      C---D---E feature-1
               \
                F---G feature-2
```

Feature-2 was branched off of Feature-1, and feature-1 has since been merged into main, but I made what I see now was likely a mistake of using a "Squash Merge" in github to do so, as it was the guidance I was given both by github (ugh) and other teams.

Now, we need to rebase feature-2 onto mainline, because Github otherwise includes commits C, D, and E in the changes for the feature-2 PR.

When I do so, I wind up with this:

```
A---B---E'---C'---D'---E'---F---G feature-2
         \
          main
```

Yeah. I'm getting a conflict for every file changed in C, D and E, which are just the changes *already present in* `E'`, and then it's replaying those commits (but they're empty!) before replaying the changes from Feature-2.

---

So anyway, this is a weird pain, but rebase is such a powerful tool, I'm sure there's a way to get it to look like I'd like, which is this:

```
A---B---E'---F---G feature-2
     \   \
      \    main
       C---D---E feature-1 (closed) (but not really, I'm still committing to it which will probably also come back and bite me...)
```

I've tried `git rebase --onto main feature-1 feature-2` per the git-rebase doc, and of course just `git rebase main`, as well as `git rebase --onto main` which just changed where my branch pointed without doing anything (I don't understand `--onto` well).

Likewise if you have any tips for keeping your repo clean when using the "github flow" (Cause I think this likely would have happened if I'd made a merge commit as well, but maybe not?), please don't hesitate! I've been using git for years, but not github (which probably spells out where I was working), and my previous knowledge just doesn't translate.

Comment: What did you get when you tried `git rebase --onto main feature-1 feature-2`? Based on your graph I think that should have worked...

Comment: @TTT: I can't know, of course, but my guess is that since `feature-1` is a branch name and hence contains ever-changing commit hash IDs, the OP moved it away from commit `E` in some way that produces some sort of undesired result. Using the raw commit hash would bypass that problem (though still leave the issue of dealing with commits added to `feature-1`, of course). An earlier `git rebase` of `feature-1` that copied `C-D-E` in it to new commits `C'-D'-E'` in it would do that, for instance.

Comment: @torek agreed that would explain it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but yeah, I tried exactly what I wrote in the question (minus branch names and actual # of commits). I cut a new branch at E (`git checkout E` -> `git checkout -b feature-1`) and then the  `git rebase --onto main feature-1 feature-2` which... didn't work, but I can't remember exactly why. Let me run again and I'll update the question with details. I'm also going to try the suggestion @eftshift0 left in the comments of his question, and I'll try with raw commit hashes as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rebase like this:

```
git rebase --onto main E feature2
```

E is the tip of the branch feature1 as it is in your feature2 branch.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but, isn't that the same as `git rebase --onto main feature-1 feature-2` which OP claims didn't work?

Comment: As torek pointed out, a likely explanation is that `feature-1` no longer points to `E`, and this answer would fix it. (Though if that's the case the last sentence may not be true.)

Comment: That is the explanation. `feature1` is currently in a different position from what it _was_. It needs to be taken care in terms of revisions of what is _currently_ the history of `feature2`. It could be also solved with `git rebase --onto main feature2~2 feature2`.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for taking the time =) Unfortunately yes, this is exactly what I tried. I was simplifying to avoid being even more verbose in the question, but `feature-1` points to E. I actually cut a new branch at E specifically for this purpose, and also tried using the hash of E directly as advised here, both of which gave me the same issues, described in the question =/

I'll try `git rebase --onto main feature2~2 feature2` and report back shortly though!

edit: realized I didn't actually describe what happened when I tried that in my question, my bad!

Comment: `feature~2` is `E` so do not expect any differences in the result.